# SQL Group with time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample table

```
id   dept   ctime
100  A      09:15:12.0000000
200  B      08:00:00.0000000
300  A      09:00:00.0000000
400  B      08:50:00.0000000
```

expect to see

```
countid   dept  xtime
2          A    08:00:00 08:50:00
2          B    09:00:00 09:15:12
```

My query

```
SELECT count(id) countid,  dept, 
        DATEADD(MI, -(DATEPART(MI, ctime) % 5), cTime) xtime
FROM table1 
GROUP BY  dept, DATEADD(MI, -(DATEPART(MI, ctime) % 5), cTime)
```

Output. But not sure why not group by hours

```
countid dept    xtime
1        B      08:00:00.0000000
1        B      08:50:00.0000000
1        A      09:00:00.0000000
1        A      09:15:12.0000000
```

Comment: Is that 2 columns in your expected output merged into one? `'08:00:00 08:50:00'` isn't a valid `time`. What is the logic here, as your `% 5` implies that you want times grouped into 5 minute intervals, but `08:50:00` is 50 minutes after `08:00:00`. What is your goal here. Actually explain the problem, don't just dump the code and expected results and expect us to guess the logic behind it.

Comment: Try to group by each hours like between 8:00:00 to 8:59:00 and 9:00:00 to 9:59:00 and by dept. Hope that make sense. Try  GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [ctime]) but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this comment, it seems you just want to aggregate to the hours:

> Try to group by each hours like between 8:00:00 to 8:59:00 and 9:00:00 to 9:59:00 and by dept.

If so, why not just use `DATEPART` with `MIN` and `MAX`?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CountID,
       Dept,
       MIN(ctime) AS MinTime,
       Max(ctrime) AS MaxTime
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Dept,
         DATEPART(HOUR, ctime);
```